# Is an ESP32 HTTP web server limited to a certain number of Base64 images?

Tags: esp32, memory

This sketch only displays about nine images (when there are more). Does this mean the ESP32 is limited amount of Base64 images able to be displayed?

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "ESP32"; 
const char* password = "12345678"; 

IPAddress local_ip(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

WebServer server(80);

// Used for determining the selected pattern and HTML to display:
int pattern = 0;
int selectedPattern = 0;

String circleString = "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" alt=\"NAME\" style=\"width:100%\">\n";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);


  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip, gateway, subnet);
  delay(100);
  
  server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);
  
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}
void loop()
{
  server.handleClient();

}

void handle_OnConnect() {

  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(selectedPattern)); 
}



void handle_NotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

String SendHTML(int pattern)
{
    String ptr = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html>\n";
    // Instance of class String (not a pointer)
    
    ptr += "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">\n";
    // <meta> viewport element makes the web page responsive in any web browser
    // https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp


    ptr += "<style type=\"text/css\">\n";
    ptr +="</style>\n";
    
    ptr +="</head>\n";
    ptr +="<body>\n";
    

      /*  */
      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 1
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";
      
      ptr +="<a class=\"button\" href=\"/circle#1\">1</a>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 2
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";

      ptr +="<a class=\"button\" href=\"/circle#1\">2</a>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 3
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";
      
      ptr +="<a class=\"button\" href=\"/circle#1\">3</a>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 4
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";

      ptr +="<a class=\"button\" href=\"/circle#1\">4</a>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 5
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";

      ptr +="<a class=\"button\" href=\"/circle#1\">5</a>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 6
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";
      
      ptr +="<a class=\"button\" href=\"/circle#1\">6</a>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 7
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";

      ptr +="<a class=\"button\" href=\"/circle#1\">7</a>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 8
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";
      
      ptr +="<a class=\"button\" href=\"/circle#1\">8</a>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 9
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";
      
      ptr +="<a class=\"button\" href=\"/circle#1\">9</a>\n";




      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 10
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 11
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 12
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";

      ptr += "<div class=\"column\">\n"; // 13
        ptr += circleString;
      ptr += "</div>\n";

 
      
   
    ptr +="</body>\n";
    ptr +="</html>\n";

    return ptr;
      
}
```

> Sketch uses 726230 bytes (55%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
> Global variables use 39384 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 288296 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.

Comment: You are including the image raw data several times in the returned string. That could blow up the memory indeed. Why don't you just include a reference to the image in the html and supply the image separately?

Comment: Because I do not know how to do that. Also, I am not sure if it matters, but this minimal program uses one image, but the actual program uses all different images.

Comment: I would need to read the docs, too. You would need to convert the image back to binary and serve it directly. And then do something like `server.on("/myimage.png", ServeImage(myimage.png))`.

Comment: did you check the html source in the browser? I guess it is cut, because the esp fails to allocate more memory for the large String

Answer (score 1):

You build up the HTML website by concatting strings together by hand in the code. I know this is done in many code throughout the internet, but this is only really practical, if you need to change the website content with every request. Normally it is better to use SPIFFS (or now LittleFS) to store the files and let a fitting webserver library serve them as static files. Additionally you are making Swiss cheese out of your heap memory when you concat `String` variables this often and you might run out of RAM.

I'm not used to LittleFS, so I will write this answer using SPIFFS. But I'm sure you can use LittleFS in a very similar way. I will leave it to you to determine how it fits in with code for SPIFFS.

Have a look at the [ESPAsyncWebServer](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer) library and its simple server example. I've used this library for my projects. Try the examples, read the documentation and get an idea how this library is working.

Then have a look at the documentation where it says "Serving static files". I think you want to serve your static files from a directory. That way the library will look for requested files in that complete directory inside of the SPIFFS. Inside that directory you will have your HTML website (named as `index.html`) and all the images as binary data in a format, that a webbrowser can read (like jpg, png, ...). In your HTML website you reference the images with their path. Since in this scenario they all lie in the root directory the path is only the filename (+ the files extension).

When the webbrowser requests the `index.html` from the ESP, the library will serve it from SPIFFS. The webbrowser interprets the site and sees the references to the images. It than tries to load these images, meaning it sends requests to the ESP with the path of the images. The library will search for these files in SPIFFS, will find them and serve them to the webbrowser, who will then display them on the website.

Something like this:

```
#include "ESPAsyncWebServer.h"
#include "SPIFFS.h"

AsyncWebServer server(80);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!SPIFFS.begin()){
    Serial.println("Could not mount SPIFFS");
    delay(500);
  }
  server.serveStatic("/", SPIFFS, "/").setDefaultFile("index.html");
  server.begin();
}

void loop(){
}
```

Note:

- I've left out all Wifi related stuff. You need to add that yourself.
- I've not tested this code, just put it together from one of my working bigger programs.
- You still need to upload the actual files to the ESP SPIFFS. There are many tutorials on how to do that. Just place your files in the root directory of SPIFFS.

Comment: LittleFS vs SPIFFS docs are at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/filesystem.rst